# any have module that have add custom step in check out page?

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, onepage-checkout

any have module or code that, just add an only New step in Checkout Page,
just only one step, no any others data from, this step.

if have, pls help me for that,
any kind of help will be appreciated.

thank you.

Comment: Asking for a walkthrough to a complete module is a bit too much for the Q&A format of this
site. Besides that, with this vague information it's not even possible to give a good answer.
We simply don't know your requirements. I'd suggest you to try starting and if you hit a
wall, ask for help here and explain exactly what you try to do, why you are doing it and
what does not work / where you need help.

Comment: i want to know that how to add only custom step in onepage checkout? for that i used extension but all extension have some form, that forms i dont want that